# Rails group_by period of variable length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, group-by

Trying to sum/average of some revenue for plotting on a chart in a Rails 4.1 application.

This is what I currently have (using the groupby gem):

```
metrics = self.all.group_by_day(:metric_date).sum(:revenue)
```

This results in a hash, like the below, which is great for daily charting.

```
p metrics #=> {"2015-04-22" => 10, "2015-04-21" => 15, "2015-04-20" => 10, etc..}
```

However, I'd also like to group these in periods of varying length, for example 30 or 7 day intervals counting back from a particular date.

I've tried using the group_by_month, group_by_week but these group them into the actual month/week, and not groups counting back from the middle of month for example.

How can I group these into a hash of intervals, while summing the values within that interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a gem for something like this: [convenient_grouper](https://github.com/humzashah/convenient_grouper)

Hope it helps.